# PostgreSQL 9.5 compatibility with ArcGIS 10.9.1 server

Tags: postgresql, arcgis-server

I have PostgreSQL 9.5 running on my server machine and I'm planning to upgrade ArcGIS server on the same machine to 10.9.1

The following link doesn't lists 9.5 as the minimum supported version:
https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/10.9.1/windows/database-requirements-postgresql.htm

Is there any way, I can keep the 9.5 version of PostgreSQL and make it compatible with ArcGIS 10.9.1? Has anyone tried this before?

Also, if I upgrade the PostgreSQL to 14.x, would it be compatible with 10.9.1?

Comment: No, neither 9.5 nor 14 are supported. Four releases are 10, 11, 12, and 13.

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.5 is over 5 years old. The expected final minor version of 9.5 was released Feb. 2021. It is now considered [end of life](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).

Comment: Note that, as per the document you referenced, if you use PG 12.x or 13.x, you *must* use `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` to upgrade, and clients older than 10.8.1 will not be able to use the resulting database.